# How to create a linked list of nodes to be used as a queue

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

Please any advice on How can I create a **linked list** of nodes to be used as a queue? I finished the node but not sure how to implement it into a queue `linked-list`. I run the program and it works getting files in order but the program must have a needed linked list structure to implement the queue.

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
    // Constructor
    Node(int a, Node* next1 = nullptr) // Constructor function inside (inline in) the struct definition
    {
        value = a;
        next = next1;
    }
};
void drawTriangle(int lines);
void displayList(Node*);
int main()
{
    // Format a DOS system command string
    string lsCmd = "ls ../../Assignment8/Assignment8/triangle*.txt > Assignment9jobQueue.txt"; //Open Assignment9jobQueue.txt to get names of triangle job files (will need to parse file names from this file)
    // Define an input file object
    ifstream triangleFile;
    // Loop looking for triangle job files
    // System call to find files
    int lines = 20;
    Node* texts = nullptr;
    string files;
    system(lsCmd.c_str());
    triangleFile.open("Assignment9jobQueue.txt");
    //getline works well for parsing out file names (store them in a queue)
    while (getline(triangleFile, files)) { // Process files in a while loop (while there are names in the file)
        ifstream temp;
        string strTemp;
        temp.open(files);
        getline(temp, strTemp);
        lines = stoi(strTemp);
        texts = new Node(lines);
        displayList(texts);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Drawing Triangle: " << endl;
        drawTriangle(lines); // Draw the triangle
        remove(files.c_str());
    }
    if (!getline(triangleFile, files)) {
        cout << "No files to process . . ." << endl;
        sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to start by having a `head` pointer.

Comment: You should at least show an attempt at building the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is just nodes pointing to nodes. You need a `head` pointer that points to the first node which you use to iterate through your linked list. A queue is first-in-first-out so you should implement a `pop()` function that removes and returns the last node of the list as well as a `push(node)` function that points to `head` then updates the `head` pointer to point to the node you just added